# How to add dynamic decimal to another decimal in a div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to be able to add a decimal from input to a decimal in a div. Here's my code below. Right now, it's just concatenating the two number next to each other. Thanks.

EDITED: Working code

```
<div id="addme">5.01</div>
<input type="text" id="anumber" value="">
<button id="add">Add Number to div</button>

$('#add').click(function() {
var number = parseFloat($('#anumber').val()) || 0;
//alert(number);
$('#addme').html(function(i, val) {
return (parseFloat(val) + number).toFixed(2);
});
});
```

Old Non-Working Code Below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="addme">5.01</div>

<input type="text" id="anumber" value="" />

<button id="add">Add Number to div</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var number = $('#anumber').val();
        if(number=='undefined' || number==''){
            var number=0;
        }
        //alert(number);
        $('#addme').html(function(i, val) {return val*1+number });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with decimal numbers, use `parseFloat()`:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var number = parseFloat($('#anumber').val()) || 0;
    $('#addme').html(function(i, val) {
        return parseFloat(val) + number;
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/47t7x/

**UPDATE**

Since you might introduce floating-point math errors (try inputing "0.6"), you should round it to a suitable number of decimal places before returning (2 if dealing with dollars and cents; 7 or more if dealing with other measurements):

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var number = parseFloat($('#anumber').val()) || 0;
    $('#addme').html(function(i, val) {
        return parseFloat((parseFloat(val) + number).toFixed(9)); 
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/47t7x/1/

Comment: I have to use return (parseFloat(val) + number).toFixed(2); to keep it at 2 decimal places. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parseInt() for this.

```
$('#addme').html(function(i, val) {return parseInt(val,10)+parseInt(number,10) });
```

Comment: Always supply a radix if you're using `parseInt` -> `parseInt(val, 10)`

Comment: You don't want to use `parseInt` with non-integer numbers.

Comment: Yes, parseInt just por Integers. Thanks for your annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you're parsing the strings to actual numeric values.

```
function(i, val) {return parseFloat(val)*1+parseFloat(number) }
```

Comment: No need to use `*1` here -- `parseFloat` always returns a number (or NaN).

Comment: @Blazemonger I just assumed the `*1` was a placeholder value for something else.

Comment: Looked to me like he was using it to convert a string into a number -- which `parseFloat` does better, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
// On the click event of #add
$('#add').on("click", function(){
    // n is equal to #anumber, or 0 if #anumber is blank
    var n = $('#anumber').val() || 0
    // Determine new HTML content for #addme
    $('#addme').html(function(i,v) {
        // Return the sum of n and v floated, to two decimal places
        return ( parseFloat(n) + parseFloat(v) ).toFixed(2);
    });
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G8nka/1/

Answer (score 0):

To convert string to number you can use the trick with `+` before string value. It will convert string value to numeric. This code works fine:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var number = +$('#anumber').val() || 0;
    $('#addme').html(function(i, val) {
        return (+val + number).toFixed(2);
    });
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/K9g49/

Comment: This chokes when a non-numerical string is entered.

Answer (score 0):

in your code it seem you want the sum, not concatenation
here is the code for sum, and you need to place that on a $(document).ready because your code was running before the objects were available.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#add').click(function(){
            var number = $('#anumber').val();
            if(number=='undefined' || number=='')
                number=0;
            var target=$('#addme');
            target.html(1*target[0].innerHTML+1*number);
        });
    });
```

if you want concatenation just remove the 1*